# Parsing a string representation of typing to get types of a child

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string representing the type of an object, in this case always a tuple, in a format consistent with how it would be written using type hinting.  So something like this;

```
Tuple[int, int]
```

I want to get out a list of types in the tuple.  Unfortunately our simple regex failed due to it not handling cases in which the type inside the object is itself a collection or union.  Ideally I should be able to take something like this:

```
Tuple[Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]], Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]
```

and get back a list with two elements:

```
Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]
Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]
```

but doing that using regex and string manipulation seems ugly and messy.  Surely this is a usecase that has come up and there is some library already for handling pulling apart typing like this?

Comment: It kinda sounds like you want to build a prefix tree?

Comment: Take a look at `print(ast.dump(ast.parse(my_text), indent=4))` and see if that will allow you to get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in Python parser, which is provided in the standard library `ast` module. Something to the effect of:

```
import ast
def extract_tuple_hints(string: str) -> list[str]:
    exp = ast.parse(string, mode="eval")
    if not isinstance(exp.body, ast.Subscript):
        raise ValueError("Expecting a subscript expression, e.g. 'Tuple[...]'")
    lines = string.splitlines()
    return [
        lines[e.lineno-1][e.col_offset:e.end_col_offset]
        for e in exp.body.slice.elts
    ]
```

Note, this assumes that the subscription expression has mutliple elements, so `Tuple[foo, bar]`, if you want to handle the case of something like `Tuple[foo]`, then you would have something slightly more messy:

```
import ast
def extract_tuple_hints(string: str) -> list[str] | str:
    exp = ast.parse(string, mode="eval")
    if not isinstance(exp.body, ast.Subscript):
        raise ValueError("Expecting a subscript expression, e.g. 'Tuple[...]'")
    lines = string.splitlines()
    slice_ = exp.body.slice
    if isinstance(slice_, ast.Tuple):
        return [
            lines[e.lineno-1][e.col_offset:e.end_col_offset]
            for e in slice_.elts
        ]
    else:
        return lines[slice_.lineno-1][slice_.col_offset:slice_.end_col_offset]
```

So, in action:

```
In [3]: import ast
   ...: def extract_tuple_hints(string: str) -> list[str] | str:
   ...:     exp = ast.parse(string, mode="eval")
   ...:     if not isinstance(exp.body, ast.Subscript):
   ...:         raise ValueError("Expecting a subscript expression, e.g. 'Tuple[...]'")
   ...:     lines = string.splitlines()
   ...:     slice_ = exp.body.slice
   ...:     if isinstance(slice_, ast.Tuple):
   ...:         return [
   ...:             lines[e.lineno-1][e.col_offset:e.end_col_offset]
   ...:             for e in slice_.elts
   ...:         ]
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return lines[slice_.lineno-1][slice_.col_offset:slice_.end_col_offset]
   ...:

In [4]: s = "Tuple[Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]], Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]"

In [5]: extract_tuple_hints(s)
Out[5]:
['Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]',
 'Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]']

In [6]: extract_tuple_hints("Tuple[int, str]")
Out[6]: ['int', 'str']

In [7]: extract_tuple_hints("Tuple[int]")
Out[7]: 'int'
```

I'd avoid returning a union type if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex does what is needed, perhaps.

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\[[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*\]
```

This regex can be broken down as follows.

```
\b         the boundary between a word char (\w) and
           something that is not a word char
------------------------------------------------------
[A-Za-z]+  any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
           possible))
------------------------------------------------------
\[         '['
------------------------------------------------------
[^\[\]]*   any character except: '[', ']' (0 or more
           times (matching the most amount possible))
------------------------------------------------------
(?:        group, but do not capture (0 or more times
           (matching the most amount possible)):
------------------------------------------------------
  \[         '['
------------------------------------------------------
  [^\[\]]*   any character except: '[', ']' (0 or
             more times (matching the most amount
             possible))
------------------------------------------------------
  \]         ']'
------------------------------------------------------
  [^\[\]]*   any character except: '[', ']' (0 or
             more times (matching the most amount
             possible))
------------------------------------------------------
)*         end of grouping
------------------------------------------------------
\]         ']'
```

```
import re

r = r'\b[A-Za-z]+\[[^\[\]]*(?:\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*\]'

test = '''Tuple[int, int]
Tuple[Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]], \
Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]'''

for match in re.finditer(r, test):
  print(match.group())
```

Output.

```
Tuple[int, int]
Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]
Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]
```

Comment: For all the great positives of the language, you have highlighted a classic point where Python fails. It just gets very messy compared to statically typed languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module, you can use a recursive regex to match your input:

```
\w+\[([^][]+|(?R))(?:,\s*((?1)))+\]
```

This matches:

- `\w+` : some word characters (to match either `Tuple` or `Union`)
- `\[` : a `[`
- `([^][]+|(?R))` : first capture group, either:

  - `[^][]+` : some number of characters which are not `[` or `]`; or
  - `(?R)` : a recursion of the entire pattern
- `(?:,\s*((?1)))+` : some number of

  - `,\s*` : a comma followed by whitespace
  - `((?1))` : a repetition of the capture group 1 expression, captured in group 2
- `\]` : a `]`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6qGeEn/1)

In python:

```
import regex

test = '''Tuple[int, int]
Tuple[Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]], \
Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]'''
pat = regex.compile(r'\w+\[([^][]+|(?R))(?:,\s*((?1)))+\]')
pat.findall(test)
```

Output:

```
[
  ('int', 'int'),
  ('Union[file.File, directory.Directory, Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]]', 'Tuple[file.File, directory.Directory]')
]
```